# How can you find and replace character in a text file in Windows command-line line by line but from a specific character appear count?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, text-files

I have a text file with a semicolon separator (CSV), it has 65 columns but the last is a "comments" column that can have semicolons in his body.
I would like to know how to write a windows batch file that count the semicolons in every line and if it finds > 64 semicolons,
deletes all the semicolons that follow after 64 (or change with a comma).
(I don´t have access to the source that builds the texts files)

Example actual:

```
marshal;Stevens;Son;11223344;Dual;this person tries food; water; fruit
```

Expected output:

```
marshal;Stevens;Son;11223344;Dual;this person tries food, water, fruit
```

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - `jrepl ";" "," /p "^((?:[^;]*;){64})(.*;)" /prepl "$1+{$2}" /f "input.csv" /o -`

Comment: First, my apologies for not post any code because sincerely my attempts really su**s but i'm glad to be able to learn, i will try all the solutions that were kindly provided by all of you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56171667.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :lop64
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:: remove the first 64 ;-terminated strings from LINE
:: remove remaining `;`

:lop64
SET /a lopoff=64
SET "original=%line%"
:lop64lp
SET "line=%line:*;=%"
SET /a lopoff-=1
IF %lopoff% gtr 0 GOTO lop64lp
CALL ECHO %%original:;%line%=%%;%line:;=%
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q56171667.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

Text-processing in batch is a minefield. You're probably better-off using `sed` or `(g)awk` which are designed for the task.

I'm assuming for lack of information otherwise that your data does not contain characters that have a special meaning to batch like `%` or `"` or `&` or `|` or `<` or `>` amongst others.

Essentially, assign the entire line read to `line`, then in the subroutine, substitute *nothing* for each string up to a `;` (`:*;=`) 64 times. Then show the original string, with the remainder in `line` substituted by *nothing* concatenated with `;` and `line`'s remainder with `;` substituted with *nothing* (`:;=`). If you want commas in place of semicolons, use `:;=,` here.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not show any own efforts to solve your task, I decided to provide some code, because it is a nice challenge – see all the explanatory `rem` remarks:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"  & rem // (input file; `%~1` is the first command line argument)
set "_SEP=;"     & rem // (original separator to be replaced)
set "_NEW=,"     & rem // (new separator to replace the old one with)
set /A "_LIM=64" & rem // (number of first original separators to be kept)

rem // Read input file line by line:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store current line, reset some auxiliary variables:
    set "LINE=%%L" & set "COLL=" & set /A "CNT=-1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Handle the case when no original separator is defined:
    if defined _SEP (
        rem // Iterate through all separated items of the current line:
        for %%I in ("!LINE:%_SEP%=" "!") do (
            rem // Support loop to transport `COLL` variable over `endlocal` barrier:
            for /F "delims=" %%J in (""!COLL!"") do (
                endlocal
                rem /* Store currently iterated item, increment item counter and
                rem    store rebuilt line with separators replaced as defined: */
                set "ITEM=%%~I" & set /A "CNT+=1" & set "COLL=%%~J"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Check whether or not to exclude current separator:
                if !CNT! gtr %_LIM% (
                    set "COLL=!COLL!!_NEW!!ITEM!"
                ) else if !CNT! gtr 0 (
                    set "COLL=!COLL!!_SEP!!ITEM!"
                ) else set "COLL=!ITEM!"
            )
        )
        rem // Return rebuilt line with separators replaced as defined:
        echo(!COLL!
    ) else echo(!LINE!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Given the script is saved as `repl-sep.bat` and the input file is called `1.csv`, run the script as follows:

```cmd
repl-sep.bat "1.csv"
```

To store the output to a file called `2.csv` rather than to display it in the console, use this command line:

```cmd
repl-sep.bat "1.csv" > "2.csv"
```

Regard that the following characters must not occur in the input file: `?`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would read in the file with a `for /f` and use `"tokens=64*delims=;"`
to get the remainder of the line and only substitute semicolons in there.

Sadly the maximum tokens value is 31 (plus * remainder), so you've to nest several `for /F`

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\16\SO_56171667.cmd
@Echo off
Set "FileIn=Col65.csv"
Set "FileOut=NewCol65.csv"

(    for /F "usebackq  delims="  %%a in ("%FileIn%"
) do for /F "tokens=31*delims=;" %%b in ("%%a"
) do for /F "tokens=31*delims=;" %%d in ("%%c"
) do for /f "tokens=2* delims=;" %%f in ("%%e"
) do Call :Sub "%%a" "%%g"
)>"%FileOut%"

Goto :Eof
:Sub
Set "Line=%~1#"
Set "Col65=%~2"
Set "Col65=%Col65:;=,%"
Call Echo:%%Line:%~2#=%Col65%%%
```

Aside from loading time this PowerShell script might be faster with larger files:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\16\SO_56171667_2.ps1
$FileIn  = 'Col65.csv'
$FileOut = 'NewCol65.csv'
Get-Content $FileIn | ForEach-Object{
  $Cols = $_ -split ';',65
  $Cols[-1] = $Cols[-1].Replace(';',',')
  $Cols -join ';'
} | Set-Content $FileOut
```

to be on topic wrapped in a batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\16\SO_56171667_2.cmd
@Echo off
Set "FileIn=Col65.csv"
Set "Fileout=NewCol65.csv"

powershell -NoP -C "gc '%FileIn%'|ForEach-Object{$Cols=$_ -split ';',65;$Cols[-1]=$Cols[-1].Replace(';',',');$Cols -join ';'}|Set-Content '%FileOut%'"
```